# Алгоритм прохода из одного угла матрицы в другую

Tags: алгоритм, delphi

Есть массив двумерный. Хочу пробежаться из верхнего правого в нижний левый с минимальными "затратам", то есть чтобы сумма значений индексов была наименьшая. У меня есть код на паскале, но никак не получается портировать его на шарп

```
   0 2 2 2 2 2 
   1 0 1 0 0 1
   2 2 2 0 2 2 
   2 2 2 0 1 0
```

Вот что должно получиться в итоге
[link text](http://s005.radikal.ru/i209/1406/f9/6c227f936dbc.png)

```
const maxn = 40;
var n, m : integer;
    a : array [1..maxn, 1..maxn] of integer;
    dist : array [1..maxn * maxn] of integer;
    bool : array [1..maxn * maxn] of boolean;

procedure readData;
var i, j : integer;
begin
  read (n, m);
  for i := 1 to n do
    for j := 1 to m do
      read (a[i, j]);
end;

function num (x, y : integer) : integer;
begin
  num := (x  - 1) * m + y;
end;

procedure solve;
var i, cur, min : integer;
    x, y : integer;
begin
  fillchar (bool, sizeof (bool), false);
  fillchar (dist, sizeof (dist), $FF);
  bool[1] := true;
  dist[1] := a[1, 1];
  cur := 1;

  while cur <> n * m do
  begin
    x := cur div m + 1;
    y := cur mod m;
    if cur mod m = 0 then
    begin
      x := x - 1;
      y := m;
    end;

    if (y > 1) and ((dist[num (x, y - 1)] = -1) or (dist[num (x, y - 1)] > dist[num (x, y)] + a[x, y - 1])) then
      dist[num (x, y - 1)] := dist[num (x, y)] + a[x, y - 1];
    if (y < m) and ((dist[num (x, y + 1)] = -1) or (dist[num (x, y + 1)] > dist[num (x, y)] + a[x, y + 1])) then
      dist[num (x, y + 1)] := dist[num (x, y)] + a[x, y + 1];
    if (x > 1) and ((dist[num (x - 1, y)] = -1) or (dist[num (x - 1, y)] > dist[num (x, y)] + a[x - 1, y])) then
      dist[num (x - 1, y)] := dist[num (x, y)] + a[x - 1, y];
    if (x < n) and ((dist[num (x + 1, y)] = -1) or (dist[num (x + 1, y)] > dist[num (x, y)] + a[x + 1, y])) then
      dist[num (x + 1, y)] := dist[num (x, y)] + a[x + 1, y];
    min := 10000;
    for i := 1 to n * m do
      if (not ((dist[i] = -1) or (bool[i]))) and (dist[i] < min) then
      begin
        min := dist[i];
        cur := i;
      end;
    bool[cur] := true;
  end;
  writeln (dist[n * m]);
end;

begin
  assign (input, 'input.txt'); reset (input);
  assign (output, 'output.txt'); rewrite (output);
  readData;
  solve;
  close (input);
  close (output);
end.
```

Comment: Вам нужны [алгоритмы поиска пути](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D1.8B)

Comment: Отлично. А что вы пробовали? Код сам не напишется.

Comment: У меня есть код на паскале. Хочу портировать под .net.

Comment: @herberus: О, уже кое-что. А что именно не получается портировать?

Comment: @herberus, минимальна сумма **именно индексов?**.

Или все же значений **элементов матрицы**.

Comment: пардон. зНачений элементов матрицы

Answer (score 2):

В таких задачах логично перейти к матрице весовых коэффициентов путей и использовать алгоритмы поиска кратчайшего пути.

Таким образом, дна основе вашей матрицы `A[n*m]` сделайте матрицы `B`, такую, что `B[i,j] = i+j`.

И для матрицы B используйте, например, [алгоритм A*](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Алгоритм_A*).